# MBED RTOS convert Float to String/Char array

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, rtos, mbed

I am trying to convert a float number to a string to send over a serial connection.
I have used sprintf and has previously worked BUT I am now running mbed RTOS which hangs when the sprintf line is reached.

Below is the line the code stops on in the while loop, Im collecting data from the mbed analogue in ports and need to display it over serial.

```
sprintf (buffer, ",%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f", sData1[0], sData1[1], sData1[2], sData1[3]);
```

I have used c_str() to translate the string back into a float number successfully under RTOS.

Is there something similar to c_str() to convert from float to string without using the sprintf method?

Comment: We have no idea if `buffer` is big enough to hold the resulting string.  Please post what `buffer` is declared as.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry, missed that. its declared as "char * buffer;"

Comment: Yes, but where is the buffer sized?  You can't simply declare an uninitialized pointer and pass it to `sprintf`.  If you did that, then it isn't surprising things are not working.  Maybe the issue all along is that you were getting away with undefined behavior and believing things were working.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My mistake I redefined buffer with a size of 250 and its working perfectly. Dont know how i managed to miss that, Thanks

Comment: Floating point operations on processors with no FPU are slow and often non-deterministic, and if an FPU *is* present, the RTOS must be able to support FPU registers in context switches - which slows downs context switches and requires additional stack space.  Often best avoided - but that is a different question.

Comment: @NoLiver92 : If that is the answer to your problem, I suggest that you delete the question, or modify it so that it at least exhibits your error.  Also that is not what `std::string::c_str()` does - it merely provides a nul terminated representation of the `std::string` object.

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` and `sprintf` functions can be very large code-wise.  Embedded IDEs typically provide multiple smaller versions of these functions that do not support all of the format specifiers such as `%f`.  You may have to choose to link with the full version of `printf` in your project's options in order for the `%f` format specifier to work.

The `printf` and `sprintf` functions also use more stack space than your average function.  Increase your program's stack size to see if perhaps a stack overflow is preventing `sprintf` from returning.

Comment: Just FYI, to see if a stack overflow happens on mbed OS, check serial output for 0x0001 error. See [here](https://developer.mbed.org/blog/entry/Tracing-stack-and-heap-overflow-errors/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread has its own stack that is likely by default much smaller then the stack allocated to a single threaded process.  Many `sprintf()` implementations use a significant amount of stack - especially for floating-point support.

It may work simply by increasing the stack for the thread concerned, but it is a lot of resource perhaps to throw at this problem.  If as it appears two decimal places is sufficient then it would be cheaper to transfer integer values scaled x100:

```
int val_x100( float val )
{
    int i = (int)(val * 1000) ;
    if( i % 10 >= 5 )
    {
        i = (i / 10) + 1 ;
    }
    else if( i % 10 <= -5 )
    {
        i = (i / 10) - 1 ;
    }
    else
    {
        i /= 10 ;
    }

    return i ;
}
```

Then:

```
sprintf( buffer, ",%d,%d,%d,%d", 
         val_x100( sData1[0] ), 
         val_x100( sData1[1] ), 
         val_x100( sData1[2] ), 
         val_x100( sData1[3] ) ;
```